# Control SP code flow based on day of week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SSIS package that executes a SP which contains a condition:

```
if (DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 2 OR DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 4 OR DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 6) 
    return 0
...
```

I was expecting that if it's Monday, Wednesday, or Friday, then the SP would continue to do things, otherwise it would `return 0` and that's it.

However, it appears that this condition succeeds EVERYDAY, and SP always returns 0 and does nothing.  I'm confused.

How do I get this to recognize MWF and continue, otherwise stop?

Thanks

Comment: SPROC means stored procedure. SSIS doesn't care what the code inside a stored procedure is, it executes by name, passing any parameters. The stored procedure will return the same results whether it's called from SSIS or executed directly in SSMS

Comment: What does `the SSIS package does not fail,` mean? Returning from a stored procedure isn't a failure. In fact, why not create a condition in SSIS so the stored procedure isn't even called on Monday, Wednesday or Friday?

Comment: Adding an expression to a precedence constraint seems simple enough here. Unless you need to execute part of a sproc, and not the rest.

Comment: replace `getdate()` with a parameter that SSIS passes to the stored procedure.  Calculate the value of that parameter using an Execute SQL Task preceding the execute task for the stored procedure, passing the value to the sproc from SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake (if I understand your issue right) is in the logic of your condition. My guess is that you actually needed `AND`s instead of `OR`s. Which can be simplified to `IN`/`NOT IN`:

```
declare @dw smallint

set @dw = DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())

if @dw in (1, 3, 5, 7)
  return 0
```

or

```
...
if @dw not in (2, 4, 6)
  return 0
```

Note, there is a [DATE_FIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) option which can alter week days order (numbers).

PS
some description:
`if (DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 2 OR DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 4 OR DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) != 6)`
this condition is always true because a single day cannot be 2nd, 4th and 6th day of week at the same time. If it is 2nd day of week, then the first condition "fails" whereas the next one succeeds because `2 != 4`.